# Processing: Numbered Image squence

Tags: processing

I am trying to create 100 frames where the numbers 0-100 are "printed" in the center of every frame. If I try the code below I get the error "It looks like you're mixing "active" and "static" modes".

```
size(1440,900);
font = loadFont("Arial-Black-96.vlw");
textFont(font,96);

int x = 0;
void draw() {
  background(204);
  y=0;
  if (x < 100) {
    text(y, 10, 50);
    x = x + 1;
    y=y+1;
  } else {
    noLoop();
  }
  // Saves each frame as screen-0001.tif, screen-0002.tif, etc.
  saveFrame(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the first 3 lines in the setup() function.
 Like:

```java
void setup(){ 
   size(1440,900);
   font = loadFont("Arial-Black-96.vlw");
   textFont(font,96); 
 }
```

I answered this without running the code, there were others issues, here a version of your code:

```java
PFont font;
int x = 0;
int size = 96;


void setup() {
  size(1440, 900);
  font = createFont("Arial-Black", size);
  textFont(font);
}

void draw() {
  background(204);

  if (x <= 100) {

    String number = nf(x, 2);
    text(number, width/2 - textWidth(number)/2, height/2);
    x++;
      saveFrame();
  } 
  else {
    exit();
  }


}
```